# Any cons for using Tuffmail?

Tags: email, hosting

I've been looking for Email hosting for some time now. I decided on fusemail for the longest because of the price, but after doing some research, it looks like they have big problems over there. I've been looking at Tuff Mail lately, and I have not found any negative feedback on the service. Also, all the extremely good reviews I have found on Tuff Mail are 1-2 years old. Does anyone currently use Tuff Mail now? Is there any way you can give me a pro/cons on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check emaildiscussions.com. You may also post this question over there.

Reuven

Comment: thanks for forum link. I found several actual reviews of Fusemail that changed my mind about using them over some others.

Answer (score 0):

I use TuffMail and find them to be excellent. In my personal experience I have found that the SPAM controls are second to none. Great customer service too, its e-mail support only but I find you get a fast reply. Usually within a couple of hours.

Tom.